# python boto fails to upload to s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I've been unable to upload my file to a bucket I've just created in my S3.

but, the other file, I upload to different bucket run normally without error.
So, I believe, the problem lies in the bucket itself instead of the code.

For now, I've granted permissions to everyone, like this[image: s3 grantee]
and, there's no policy either.

and this is my cors bucket:

```
 <CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

this is the snapshot of mycode

```
class Handler:

    ...

    def s3save(self, local_path, remote_path, metadata=None, savebucket=None):
        chunk_size = Handler.CHUNK_SIZE
        headers = self.default_s3_headers if metadata is None else metadata
        mpu = savebucket.initiate_multipart_upload(
            remote_path,
            headers=headers,
            policy="public-read"
        )

        # code copy-ed from someone from stackoverflow
        source_size = os.stat(local_path).st_size
        chunk_count = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(chunk_size)))
        print(local_path, remote_path, savebucket)
        for i in xrange(chunk_count):
            offset = chunk_size * i
            bytelength = min(chunk_size, source_size - offset)
            with FileChunkIO(local_path, "r", offset=offset, bytes=bytelength) as fp:
                mpu.upload_part_from_file(fp, part_num=i + 1)
        mpu.complete_upload()
```

but regardless, I still got this error:

```
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: `print(local_path, remote_path, savebucket)` :) Send is Stdout.

Comment: @dsgdfg, what do you mean?
but, I doubt IO is the problem, because, I use the same function to upload 3 different file.

2 to different bucket, and those 2 file, uploaded normally.